# How do I select a value whose id don't exist as parent to others, in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Two questions:

1. My table has three fields: `id`, `parent_id`, `name`. Initially `id`
   is `0`, for an element that is a child to the current element, the
   `parent_id` is set to the `id` of the current element....basically,
   infinite nesting concept. Now I need to find those elements which do
   not have any children or sub-elements. Any ideas?
2. What is the best choice to retrieve the `id`(auto_increment) of a
   record I just inserted? mysql_insert_id or last_insert_id, or
   something else? I need to insert two records simultaneously and use
   the id(primary key) from the first record as foreign key of second
   record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
SELECT * FROM `nestmenu` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `parent_id` AS `id` FROM `nestmenu`)
```

However, as you can tell, this query is not at all optimized, but it does get the job done. Any ideas how to optimize it?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions I and others have made? They do work and MySQL tends to optimize joins better than subqueries...

Comment: Yep I did try, and your suggetion did not give me the result I need

Answer (score 0):

1) Not sure I understand your schema and how parent_id works...

```
SELECT
  t1.id
FROM
  table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table t2
ON
  t1.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE
  t2.parent_id IS NULL
```

2)  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is the function which returns the last autoincrement generated on the connection. I don't know what `mysql_insert_id` was referring to... `mysql_last_insert_id` in PHP perhaps? That's a PHP function that wraps a call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: It is a hierarcical database model.

Comment: That much is understood, but there's more than one way to represent that hierarchy.

Comment: Insightful, Dan have you any reference to examples? I am also trying to implement this in one of my projects but have only come across this.

Answer (score 0):

1. use **SELF JOIN**

> ```
> SELECT f.is,f.parent_id,f.name FROM table f
> LEFT JOIN table s ON s.id = f.parent_id
> WHERE s.parent_id = 0
> ```

1. use `last_insert_id`